# GameObject get position relative to grandparent

Tags: unity-game-engine

`transform.localPosition` gives me the location relative position to the parent. `transform.parent.transform.localPosition` gives me the location of the parent relative to the grandparent. What I need is the local position of a child object, but relative to the grandparent and not relative to the parent. How can this be achieved in unity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Tranform.InverseTransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html) to get any world position in the local space of any Transform.

```
    Vector3 grandParentLocalPosition = transform.parent.parent.InverseTransformPoint(transform.position);
```

This will get the grandparent transform (`transform.parent.parent`), then put the world position of the current object (`transform.position`) into the local space of the grandparent.

Comment: I don't understand the documentation of `InverseTransformPoint`. Does what you wrote give me the position of the grandparent relative to the grandchild or the other way around?

Comment: @Ceolando It gives you the position of the grandchild (`transform.position`) relative to the position and rotation of the grandparent (`transform.parent.parent`).

Comment: I've tried to clarify my wording for you @Ceolando, let me know if that makes my answer clearer.

Comment: @NSJacob1 Yes, I already accepted your answer. Thank you very much I got it to work!